# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'finalproject'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - MySQL access denied error - Works in other programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112443/php-mysql-access-denied-error-works-in-other-programs)

i'm trying to make a login process that connect between my AdminLogin2.php and admin2 table inside my phpmyadmin, but it said access denied. i've no idea what should i do to fix it..Hope someone can help me here. here my code, Thank You.

```
`<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="finalproject";
$table="admin2";

$AdminID=$_POST['Field1'];
$Password=$_POST['Field3'];

mysql_connect("$host","$password") or die (mysql_error());
#echo"connected";
mysql_select_db("$database") or die (mysql_error());
#echo"database found";

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$AdminID = stripslashes($AdminID);
$Password = stripslashes($Password);
$AdminID = mysql_real_escape_string($AdminID);
$Password = mysql_real_escape_string($Password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $admin2 WHERE username='$AdminID' and password='$Password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:AdminForm.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

`

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are [in the deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql_connect("$host","$password")
```

it should be like

```
mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password")
```

thats why you getting error with empty username from database

Comment: thank you ! it's work..sorry , i'm new on this thing. learn from mistake. again, thank you very mych @Wilq . :)

Comment: you should accept his answer if it is the right one.